# How do I create an Image of a VM using Azure Resource Manager

Tags: azure

I've been using the classic Azure Portal for a while now, and I know how to create a VM, customize it, then capture it as an Image and use that image to create more VMs.
Now I'm trying to use the new Azure Portal.  I created the VM and customized it, now I want to capture an image so I can make more VMs exactly the same way.  The problem is the new web portal doesn't capture option.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can do it via Powershell:

```
Login-AzureRmAccount
Get-AzureRmSubscription
Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId "<subscriptionID>"

Stop-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName <resourceGroup> -Name <vmName>
Set-AzureRmVm -ResourceGroupName <resourceGroup> -Name <vmName> -Generalized
Save-AzureRmVMImage -ResourceGroupName <resourceGroupName> -Name <vmName> `
     -DestinationContainerName <destinationContainerName> -VHDNamePrefix <templateNamePrefix> `
     -Path <C:\local\Filepath\Filename.json>
```

For more details visit: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-windows-capture-image

Comment: So there is no way to do that in the portal?  Thats weird since AWS, GCP, HyperV, OpenStack, ProfitBricks, XenServer and VMWare all allow me to create images.

Comment: more over, even the old portal allows for that, but the new one does - yet.